# How to compare generic number type

Tags: go, generics, type-assertion

I have a validation function Positive, it's works but looks ugly.

```
type Positiver interface {
    decimal.Decimal | int | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | uint | uint8 | uint16 | uint32 | uint64 | float32 | float64
}

//nolint:cyclop
func Positive[T Positiver](value T, name string, errs *[]error) {
    addError := func() {
        err := fmt.Errorf(`%s %w, but it's %v`, name, failures.ShouldBePositive, value)
        *errs = append(*errs, err)
    }

    const prescision = 8

    switch val := any(value).(type) {
    case decimal.Decimal:
        if val.IsNegative() || val.IsZero() {
            err := fmt.Errorf(`%s %w, but it's %s`, name, failures.ShouldBePositive, val.StringFixedBank(prescision))
            *errs = append(*errs, err)
        }

        return
    case int:
        if val <= 0 {
            addError()
        }
    case int64:
        if val <= 0 {
            addError()
        }
    case int32:
        if val <= 0 {
            addError()
        }
    case int16:
        if val <= 0 {
            addError()
        }
    case int8:
        if val <= 0 {
            addError()
        }
    case uint:
        if val <= 0 {
            addError()
        }
    case uint64:
        if val <= 0 {
            addError()
        }
    case uint32:
        if val <= 0 {
            addError()
        }
    case uint16:
        if val <= 0 {
            addError()
        }
    case uint8:
        if val <= 0 {
            addError()
        }
    case float32:
        if val <= 0 {
            addError()
        }
    case float64:
        if val <= 0 {
            addError()
        }
    default:
        panic(fmt.Sprintf(`%T is not supported type`, val))
    }
}
```

I know that is bad approach to use []error, it's better just to return a wrapped error.
But it's a compatibility issue.

I tried to do like this:

```
func Positive[T Positiver](value T, name string, errs *[]error) {
    switch val := any(value).(type) {
    case decimal.Decimal:
        if val.IsNegative() || val.IsZero() {
            err := fmt.Errorf(`%s %w, but it's not`, name, failures.ShouldBePositive)
            *errs = append(*errs, err)
        }

        return
    case int, int8, int16, int32, int64, uint, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64:
        if val.(int64) <= 0 {
            err := fmt.Errorf(`%s %w, but it's not`, name, failures.ShouldBePositive)
            *errs = append(*errs, err)
        }

        return
    case float32, float64:
        if val.(float64) < 0 {
            err := fmt.Errorf(`%s %w, but it's not`, name, failures.ShouldBePositive)
            *errs = append(*errs, err)
        }

        return
    default:
        panic(fmt.Sprintf(`%T is not supported type`, val))
    }
}
```

But this approach returns me an error:
test panicked: interface conversion: interface {} is int, not int64

What is a better way to compare that value exceeds zero?

Comment: 1. It makes no sense to compare any uint type to < 0 (both variants). 2. I doubt you gain much by using generics here. 3. Fix the bug in the second variant by replacing val.(int64) with `int64(val)` (the float case analog).

Comment: the issue with your code is mainly that you are not comparing a "generic number type" because in the union you also have `decimal.Decimal` which is a struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work with "interface conversion: interface {} is int, not int64" because in multiple-type `case` the type switch variable `val` keeps its original type. See also: [golang multiple case in type switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575033/golang-multiple-case-in-type-switch) for details.

So in this case you have indeed to assert to something in order to use the order operators. That "something" **could** be a type parameter.

```
    case int, int8, int16, int32, int64:
        if val.(T) <= 0 {
            // ...
        }
```

**BUT** this code still can't use the order operator because the constraint `Positive` includes `decimal.Decimal`, which doesn't support ordering.

Attempting to write a `case` for `decimal.Decimal` and a `case` for other numeric types won't work well either, because you haven't a good way to reduce the type set of a type constraint. You are back writing one `case` for each type. One day Go might allow using union constraints in type switches.

What you can do today is to statically handle `decimal.Decimal` and other numeric types differently. You can use the types in the package [`constraints`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints) to avoid redeclaring everything: [`Signed`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints#Signed), [`Unsigned`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints#Unsigned) and [`Float`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/constraints#Float). Then a naive function with only numerical types is as simple as this:

```
func StrictlyPositive[T Signed | Unsigned | Float](v T) bool {
    return v > 0
}
```

**BUT** with floats, using `<` is not enough. Float variables could also be NaN or +/-infinity. You have to decide how to order NaNs; infinities have the sign bit, but IMO it's better to use `math.IsInf` to not hide stuff behind the order operators.

So in conclusion I think this function is better off with reflection, which might be slower, but the code doesn't *totally* suck. The following is a simplified version of your example:

```
func CheckPositive[T Positive](value T) string {
    switch val := any(value).(type) {
    case decimal.Decimal:
        if val.IsNegative() || val.IsZero() {
            return "non positive decimal"
        }

    case int, int8, int16, int32, int64:
        if reflect.ValueOf(val).Int() <= 0 {
            return "non positive signed"
        }

    case uint, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64:
        if reflect.ValueOf(val).Uint() == 0 {
            return "non positive unsigned"
        }

    case float32, float64:
        f := reflect.ValueOf(val).Float()
        switch {
        case math.IsNaN(f):
            return "NaN float"
        case math.IsInf(f, -1):
            return "negative infinite"
        case math.IsInf(f, 1):
            // do nothing
        default:
            // not a NaN and not an Infinite
            if f <= 0.0 {
                return "negative float"
            }
        }

    default:
        panic(fmt.Sprintf(`%T is not supported type`, val))
    }
    return "positive"
}
```

Comment: Infs could be handled properly by < and the total paranoid would probably want to treat -0 and +0 differently and contemplate if 0 is positive or negative.